# Replace string output from query in results tab

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a DB with a large number of CLOB columns. Each of these columns contains a repeated set of characters, which are fillers designed to designate a paragraph break (I didn't design the tables).

Is there a way to write the script so that each time the script finds these characters it enters a paragraph or line break into the results that are returned, while still saying in the same row of the results?

The data would look like

> "Hello all,XYZ!£$I can't get ... to work.XYZ!£$The error meassge says ..."

As an example:

```
SELECT *

FROM ALERTS

REPLACE(Alert_Text, 'XYZ!£$', CH(13))
```

(Obviously the above returns errors)

The ideal output of the query would be:

> "Hello all,
>
> I can't get ... to work.
>
> The error meassge says ..."

I am using SqlDbx to connect to an Oracle DB.

Comment: By the way, the linefeed character (10) generally does the job, or you can concatenate carriage return (13) + linefeed for a Windows-specific file, but carriage return on its own doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *obvious* error is `ORA-00904: "CH": invalid identifier`

The reason is, that the function name is [`CHR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CHR.html)

```
select REPLACE(txt, 'XYZ!£$', CHR(13)) from tab;

REPLACE(TXT,'XYZ!£$',CHR(13))                                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hello all,
I can't get ... to work.
The error meassge says ...
```